# Methods of permanently joining a metal mask to a face

Tags: religion, metals, metalworking

There exists an extremist religious order whose tenets espouse the rejection of vanity and self-interest - to achieve nothing less than the complete erasure of the sense of self, instead devoting oneself solely to the needs of others. This order's members adorn themselves with clothing that obscure even the slightest glimpse of flesh - and a mask, an identifying symbol of their devotion, which many believe is permanently sealed to their face.

The initial idea was inspired by Edward Norton's portrayal of King Baldwin IV in *Kingdom of Heaven* mixed with a little Darth Vader, so I want to say this mask is some kind of metal for now. What could be done (however painful) to permanently apply a mask like that? Assume the level of technology is mid-19th century.

Side note: not really sure what tags to put this under, so I'm adding a few that I think might be relevant. I'll add or edit them (if I can) if people have any ideas!

Comment: Should we assume the mask is jointed to allow the wearer to eat, or do they have some way around that restriction? (Or do they actually remove it, presumably in private?)

Comment: This was something I thought about bringing up in the question, but wasn't sure if it was appropriate or better for a separate one. Let's just assume they never remove it; once it's on, it's on for good - though I suppose it could be removed forcefully with a medical procedure. 

With that said, yes, let's also assume there's a method by which the mask can be lifted or at least opened slightly around the mouth to permit eating.

Comment: What rate of success you are looking for? What % of patients should survive long-term with attached mask?

Comment: Alexandre Dumas's *The Man in the Iron Mask* was based on the story of a man who had a red-hot mask placed onto his face so that it was seared onto it. A bit gruesome and certainly incredibly painful.

Comment: @Halfthawed  *The Man in the Iron Mask* was apparently based on a real prisoner who had a *velvet* mask on.  See [Wikipedia's entry on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_in_the_Iron_Mask).

Comment: Wouldn't the skin under the mask quickly become irritated, then festering, and then it goes downhill?

Comment: @Vilx- Yes, gold and platinum might work well enough to be practical. (They can retain a dense and smooth surface better. And do not contaminate the body with toxic or allergenic garbage as much.)

Comment: /does this answer your question? Insterad of gem you put sheet of metal shaped like umbrella https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167093/could-people-feasibly-have-gems-implanted-in-their-bones

Comment: @VilleNiemi I was thinking more about simply poor airflow, precipitation, no possibility of cleaning, and constant rubbing of metal against skin. That alone should be enough I think, without even involving any potentially toxic metals.

Comment: @Vilx- Yes, that too. The issues you get depend on what you mean with "permanent".

Comment: 12 inch piece of allthread through the center of the individuals skull? Of course a flat washer and a bolt on both ends

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## It's not actually affixed to their face, people just think it is.

Simply put, anything that would break the skin on a long-term basis causes a large risk of infection. At the technology level you've presented, this would result in unavoidable death, especially since we're talking about something affixed to your head. This is why, in real life, companies that are researching cybernetic implants are designing their implants to work without breaking the skin once implanted. Additionally, by wearing something non-stop against the skin, you're trapping dead skin, bacteria, sweat, and similar things against the skin and increasing the risk of infection further - this is why soldiers have to regularly change their socks to avoid trench-foot, for instance.

So, rather than actually affixing their mask to their heads, just have them always wear their mask when they're publicly visible. They could remove their mask in private to bathe or eat, but whenever people see them, they're always wearing their masks, and that gives rise to a rumor that they can't remove their masks among more credulous individuals.

Comment: Considering that at times wearing the mask might be seen as **being** vanity and virtue-signalling (e.g. Parable of the Pharisee and the Tax Collector, et cetera), there *may* be circumstances under which the religion *requires* that the mask not be worn - but that you must **also** not declare your religious affiliation at those times.  A sort of reverse-masquerade.  Then the faithful would have active reason to **encourage** those rumours...

Comment: Crossref to existing media: The Mandalorian. Your last paragraph literally describes the rule followed by the main character there.

Comment: All of these answers have been great--and some very gruesome--but I think this will ultimately be what needs to happen. The risk of infection, rotting flesh, lack of hygiene, etc., can't be ignored, and I don't really want to handwave it away with some magical solution or something. They could maybe wear a veil or cloth over their head instead, and wear the masks over that when out in public.

Comment: @Vigilant why not both? A black cloth will block the eyes from being visible in the eyeholes, while still keeping some semblance of eyesight for the wearer - and  when silvered glasses come into fashion in the 1980s, your cult will adopt them pretty much immediately.

Answer (score 21):

## Put the mask on before they're adult.

Simply put, have them grow into their mask. If the mask is properly shaped (like a ball with a hole for the neck), it will be impossible to take it off. If you do this while they are young enough, their head will adapt to the shape of the mask ([Artificial cranial deformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_cranial_deformation)).

At the time where you put it on, the head will be barely small enough to pass through the "hole" for the neck - and after they've grown enough, it won't be able to pass through again.

[image: Medieval Helmet]

This helmet would work, if the hole for the neck was smaller.

The mask can leave the skin unharmed, as there can be space left - just not enough for the head to be drawn out of the mask.

[image]

<s>This could be a head.</s>

Well phrased clarification by @EveryBitHelps in a comment:

> The mask itself doesn't have to be tiny tiny. Just the neck opening. Only once the kiddo has grown into the mask then they won't be able to take it off. The effort and hassle of wearing a mask that is too big for you while you wait to grow into it could be seen as a sign of dedication to the religion or training in self discipline etc.

Comment: So the whole cult has tiny heads?  Do you ever write horror novels?  And if not, have you considered it?

Comment: Well, if they can only afford tiny helmets, they will have tiny heads... Just considered it right now, but I actually prefer writing different stuff (programs).

Comment: The mask itself doesn't have to be tiny tiny. Just the neck opening. Only once the kiddo has grown into the mask then they won't be able to take it off. The effort and hassle of wearing a mask that is too big for you while you wait to grow into it could be seen as a sign of dedication to the religion or training in self discipline etc.

Comment: @EveryBitHelps Updating the answer to include your clarification.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonsai_Kitten

Comment: This is a brilliant answer.  I would have said 'it can't be done' until I saw this answer.

Comment: This assumes a minimum head and maximum neck size. I was in Army Basic with an enormous guy we called Kevlar. This was due to the largest helmet on base looking like a beanie on him. I'm not a small guy, so I'm sure even a neck hole for him, me, and DanikaPatrick are all going to be very different. I'm also sure that a helmet mask for Kevlar would be completely unsuitable and unwieldy for Danika, let alone a 6 year old. Also, if you have someone end up like Goldberg, their neck is larger than their head, so anything that would trap a head would void any real weight lifting.

Answer (score 13):

Use the jaw.

Dental fittings can be installed by pinning into the jawbone. The gums then heal around the pins/false teeth. If you tear out and replace all of the teeth in the upper jaw you could replace them with metal fixings, onto which the mask could (later once the mouth has healed) be affixed via the aperture of the mouth., Keep space between the mask and the face, and also allow for brushes to get in and clean the gums (oral hygiene will be *vital*), and you can have a permanent (as in can’t easily be removed) mask. Warning: there is a risk of drool.

Now, this requires methods of dentistry and medical grade metals that I think are unavailable at your technological level. Medical grade titanium is hard enough to make, and the pins would either cause large chunks of the face to go numb or be in constant agony unless done very well (seriously, there’s a reason dentists have to train for so long. The nerves in the face are *insane*). There’s also a very high risk of infection, but I think that’s pretty much a given anyway.

Oh, and don’t make the mask too heavy, or it could tear away, causing unfathomable trauma. I mean... eurgh...

But handwave away the metal and ignore the potential for agony (mad cultists, right?) and it’s vaguely plausible, if a touch disgusting.

Comment: That is a very gross and disturbing answer, and yet I have to upvote it for a creative solution!

Comment: To make it a little easier, it's not the mask itself that is embedded, but a wire/chain that is connected to the mask. Same result, less chance for a bumped head to result in a broken jaw...

Answer (score 10):

You can rivet it on.

The mask doesn't need to be embedded in the vic^Wadherent's flesh in any way; in fact, for health reasons, it *shouldn't* be. However, that isn't required for the mask to be irremovable; it just needs to wrap around the head in such a way that it can't be removed. The rigidity of metal will help with this, as will the extent to which the mask is "fitted" to the face. If it fits well enough, you might only need a strap/band behind the head to keep it in place.

The easiest way would be to use rivets. The convert(s) places the mask over their face, then lie, face down, with their head in a specially shaped block such that the two tabs on the front piece of the mask sit over sturdy metal blocks. The back band is placed over their head and lined up. A heated slug of metal is placed through the aligned holes in the side tabs on the front and back of the mask. A rod-like metal tool is placed over the slug and struck with a hammer. The shape of the tool, and the blocks on the other side, cause the metal slug (still hot enough to deform) to mushroom outwards on both sides. (You can also have the rivet already mushroomed on one side, but this might make the process harder.) The resulting rivet cannot be removed except by cutting, and I'm not sure they would have had the technology to do that back then. (Even today, it would be dangerous to cut metal so close to the skull.)

Alternatively, there are other techniques known back then to join metal (soldering, brazing) that might be accomplished without killing the vic^Wadherent, though I'm less sure how you'd design your components to allow such a join.

Things will probably be a lot easier if you stick to the style of mask that only covers the eyes and nose. (No problems eating, for example.) This may or may not be irremovable on its own, but if you attach it to a collar with a band running vertically from the bridge of the nose to the back of the neck, it won't be going anywhere.

BTW, anyone wearing such a mask is going to have to watch their weight...

Comment: "The resulting rivet cannot be removed except by cutting, and I'm not sure they would have had the technology to do that back then." Handsaws existed back then. It'd just take a long time to cut through metal.

Comment: Trying to get metal to the point of melting without also melting or at least extremely damaging flesh is not very feasible. Solder is pretty easy to melt, yet I have scars from that, including one spot that removed all the layers of skin before it got cold enough to stop burning me. In the time frame the OP talks about, antibiotics weren't very prominent and a religious order likely wouldn't use them as they are "witchcraft", or some such nonsense, so severe infection would be completely unavoidable and death likely.

Comment: That's a problem of convection and insulation. Asbestos might help (remember, they won't know about the bad effects yet), or maybe wool (or even just leather), or just pouring a lot of water over the metal while you're working. In general, though, you're right that my alternatives are probably more dangerous than riveting. That said, people (and cattle, but they have thicker skin) have been surviving branding for a long time.

Answer (score 6):

I have heard of an experimental procedure in the 19th century as a means of fixing dentures. This was done by drilling into the top of the skull, and fixing a threaded rod through the head from the top of the skull through tho the roof or the mouth, where the dentures would be fixed.

Similarly I have heard a story of a man who I a workplace accident had a metal rod blasted through his head from his chin through the top of his skull. The man miraculously escaped death as the rod went perfectly between the two halves of the brain, with minimal damage to either.

(apologies, I am struggling to find the documentation for my examples, I'll try and update later)

The point is, the same principle can be applied when fixing a permanent mask. A skilled doctor can fix a rod through someone's skull as a base, and perhaps at less vulnerable spots add support for this (below the eyes for example). This will quickly become a permanent part of the skull when (or if) it heals. Removing this can be excruciating, if not impossibly dangerous.

Comment: That'd cause a big risk of infection. There's a reason why modern research into cybernetic implants is all looking at ways to make the implants work without breaking the skin.

Comment: @nick012000 oh yeah I completely agree. This would be incredibly dangerous, with the success rate much lower than one would like. But that is besides the point.

Comment: @nick012000: the mouth has some special properties when it comes to things poking through the surface. Not sure about the roof of the mouth, but the gums seem to be OK with the existence of teeth.

Comment: We can use some toxic metals like lead or silver. It will reduce infection risk. And who cares about long life in that conditions?

Comment: -1 "However painful" and "however dangerous" are two very different goals. When the large majority of your members are going to die it's hard to justify in the best of cases. In a group of people that devotes itself to the needs of others the idea that they would  basically murder each other is just terrible world building. Without the "needs of others" as the goal it would've required a lot less suspension of disbelief.

Comment: @DavidMulder I disagree, one could see this ritual as a sign of their devotion. The fact it could be lethal just adds to the sacrifice people are willing to make for others. Also I don't think the lethality will be a majority, especially if this has been practiced for a while, one does not have to be an advanced brain surgeon to avoid hitting the brain lobes.

Comment: The man with the rod you are referring to is Phineas P. Gage, and the rod went through his left frontal lobe. At first he seemed miraculously unimpaired, as if that part of the brain did nothing. Eventually people noticed his personality was altered, and he lost his sense of morals, giving a better idea of what that area actually holds.   As far as the denture thing, I have not heard of that, and it is so creepy I don't know if I want it to be true or not true!

Comment: This feels more like trying to find correlations for one off cases ("I heard of a case where x happened, so y must be possible").  There's a big difference between one case with very special circumstances compared to hundreds of thousands of normal cases.  The amount of trial and error they would have to go through alone would be enough to kill a small village (remember no way to see where the rod is going).  I don't think suspension of belief would work for me in this scenario.

Answer (score 6):

**Piercings**

Numerous small surface piercings in the skin provide anchor points for the mask. The weight is distributed across these piercings, so they don't need to be large gauge, just numerous.

Technically, the mask and piercings are occasionally removed so that they can be cleaned, elsewise these priests would get horrible infections all over their head/face. But this would be an infrequent and private occurrence.

As an added bonus, even sans mask, all those metal bits hanging off their face would be pretty gnarly looking, especially in a culture that was otherwise unused to facial piercings.

Comment: This is very similar to what I was thinking in regards to the OP's question.  I was thinking straps around the head would hold the weight of the mask, while the mask could be secured to the face using sub-dermal implants.  The implants basically have threaded bolts that would be able to stick out through holes in the mask and the mask is secured by screwing a nut onto the bolt.  This would then allow the removal of the mask for necessary medical reasons and cleaning, and could also allow for refitting should the shape and size of the person's face change.

Comment: @R.McMillan I had considered a strap as well, but felt that it went somewhat against the 'flavor' of the original question. Really, the skin of the face may be too elastic to work as a permanent mount point, but I thought this was close enough to be handwaved away in the name of artistic license. If there were some method of reliably permanently rendering them bald, that would open up the back of the skull for additional mount points, but I couldn't think of a way to do that.

Answer (score 5):

**A Modified Scold’s Bridle**

[image]

[Scold’s Bridles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scold's_bridle), also called witch’s bridles, were cruel punishment/torture devices used on mostly on women, originating in the 16th century. *Please note that I do not condone the use of such devices, even in history*; I am simply explaining their usage as a sort of illustration. They were publicly humiliating masks the people had to wear, due to being suspected witches because of ‘scolding’ in public, or ‘gossiping’ and ‘rioting’. A spike embedded into a ball near the tongue would pierce into the tongue when the wearer attempts to speak or eat, making such actions impossible. It also could be a metal piece pressing the tongue down instead, causing it to be very difficult to speak coherently.

**The Virtue Mask**

It is difficult to imagine joining metal to the face as there are frankly too many biological consequences, but instead your mask can be a sort of scold’s bridle. These masks have the advantage of **being able to be put on whenever one joins the religious order**. There would be spikes on the back of the mask, which would not hurt the user when they put it on, but when one tries to remove it, spikes pierce into the back of the head, so effectively, it stays on. In mask form, it would look similar to the following, but have spikes that extend the opposite way, for when the user tries to remove it (from JoJo’s Bizarre Adventure):
[image]

The public can see how the mask is attached, so the mask is like a symbol of virtue, representing a sort of lifetime dedication to their cause, rather than the humiliation associated with a Scold’s. Just please change the mask design into something more plain, otherwise the public would be absolutely frightened instead.

If spikes are too much, instead, the mask can be two metal halves (like a helmet), and be melded together after being placed around a person’s face. Or, it could be a mask welded with metal straps on the back of the head.

The mask should be slightly larger than the person’s head, to prevent the welding heat from searing the person’s face forever, or it could be nearly face fitting **searing a vertical scar into the side of their head forever as it is welded on** (shudders). If your story is to feature deserters often, and the religion is extremist even in extremist religions, I would say the form fitting mask would be ideal. Otherwise, the large mask (more like a helmet) may be nice, serving as a symbol of the religion.

Comment: I think the idea of a mask with spikes angled so that they only pierce you when trying to take it off, rather than put it on (fish hook style) is a pretty elegant solution.

Comment: @CaptainSkyfish yup, I will clarify that in the question too.

Comment: Unfortunately, the spike helmet seems it would be possible to doff with just a pair of metal sheets between the spikes and the skin.

Comment: @JohnDvorak It’s a part of the symbolism, and constant pain that they would have to endure.

Comment: @JohnDvorak if the mask doesn’t work, they can just weld a helmet around the face, as given in the alternate part of the answer

Answer (score 2):

> (...) a mask, an identifying symbol of their devotion, which many believe is permanently sealed to their face.

That's not really a mask. Those guy are just really ugly.

Seriously now, you've gotta irritate and multilate the flesh, making it so that the whole skin is wounded and looks like rust ([kinda like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YPry.jpg)). Then paralyze the facial muscles. Those guys will only be able to swallow preprocessed food, but that's softcore in comparison to other crazy things people did in the past for their beliefs.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make the helmet as two halves that join together with nuts and bolts.
2. The helmet has some openable small windows for performing hygiene and allowing room for hairs and a beard grow up out of the mask.
3. Make sure that the mask is tight enough in the neck to make it impossible to be removed pulling it upwards without separating both parts. But obviously, not too tight to injury the user.
4. Weld the nuts and bolts.

Then, the mask can be removed only by breaking up the nuts and bolts. This actually happens once in a while for allowing full hygiene, treating wounds, cutting hair or simply replacing an old mask with a new one if/when needed, however this requires the aid of someone else and will take at least a couple of minutes (at least if we want the subject alive, of course).

Answer (score 1):

You could probably, with enough practice, create a method to drill curved spikes into the wearer's head without hurting the important parts too much. After the spikes have healed a little you could just weld the mask onto the ends. Yeah it'd be painful, but that's could be part of becoming one with the whole. The curved spikes would make sure to anchor the mask, it'd take a bit of breaking and tearing in order to remove the mask and the victim probably wouldn't survive the blood loss given the technology.